# Auto Create Database Tables from Objects, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to do this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs but instead of using the compact edition of SQL Server I am using a full install on my local machine.  The way I read this tutorial is that the Entity Framework is suppose to create the tables from the objects I have defined. My problem is that I keep getting invalid object name dbo.movies, when I run the project.  I finally got it to run by creating the table myself so I know the connection string and everything was correct.

My question is, is it possible to generate tables from objects created in C# and if so how?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> is it possible to generate tables from objects created in C#?

Yes it is possible. Did you happen to create the Database manually in Management Studio before running the Code? That could be your problem. With Code First, the default convention is to create the database if it does not exist already. If the database already exists (even without the tables) then it is going to just use the existing database (but it won't try and create the tables).

You can either delete the database and try and run the code again to see if it will create it for you or put the following line in Global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourDbContextHere>());
```

Once it has run then I would suggest changing that line to:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDbContextHere>());
```

These namespaces are defined in `System.Data.Entity`

The `DbContext` class also exposes a Database property which defines the following useful methods:

```
Delete()
Create()
CreateIfNotExists()
```

So if you defined your class like so:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {}
```

You can construct an instance like so:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();
db.Database.Delete();
db.Database.Create();
```

Comment: Hmm, what am I suppose to put into the connection string if there isn't an initial database for it to connect to?  I just delete the initial catalog piece from it and received the same Invalid object name 'dbo.Movies' error.

Comment: The Connection String tells it where to create the database. It doesn't have to exist. It's going to detect that it doesn't exist and then attempt to create it if it does not. As long as it has the correct permissions, everything will get created fine. I think if you delete the database and keep the same connection string then everything will end up working the way you want it to.

Comment: Oh, awesome thank you very much! One last question which method would you recommend putting the Database.SetInitializer in.  I got an error that it couldn't drop the database because it was in use.  I would presume by the application its self.  Thanks again, my friend and I spend a lot of time searching trying to figure out the problem and would have never guessed that it was that the database shouldn't alread be created.

Comment: I would probably put it in Global.asax for now. If you had some database specific boostrapper it might go in there but for small projects Global.asax is fine. Make sure you always dispose your DbContext objects or else you are going to run into problems deleting the database. It probably thinks there is still an active connection to your database right now.

Answer (score 4):

```
ModelContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Comment: pls explain your question.

Comment: @DakshMiglani it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Linq-to-Sql DataContext you can inject the structure directly into your Database whith:

```
DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext(connectionString);
db.CreateDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is kosher, but using code-first EF, when I use AddRange, EF will typically create all the tables I've defined.  I wanted to keep the database because there are other tables I wanted to keep between application runs.  I discovered that the tables would not be re-created after they were deleted if I did not also delete the table EF created called __MigrationHistory.

Once I deleted this table, then EF would re-create the tables without having to re-create the database.

This may not be an advisable approach in production, but for my development needs this resolved my issue.  Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FenixRepo](https://github.com/SlavaUtesinov/FenixRepo) library(also available as [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FenixRepo/)) to create particular table, that is a part of you `Context`. First of all, you should call one time, at startup `static` `Initialize` method, where first argument is a factory method, which returns instance of your `Context` and the second one is an instance of `Configuration` `class`. It will prepare SQL scripts for all of your tables, registered at your `Context`. At case of ASP.NET MVC it is a good decision to paste this code into Global.asax:

```
FenixRepositoryScriptExtractor.Initialize(() => new Context(), new Configuration());
```

Then you can create table of desired type `MyTable` this simple way:

```
var repo = new FenixRepositoryCreateTable<MyTable>();
//or repo = new FenixRepository<MyTable>();

repo.CreateTable();
```

Also, if your table spread between several migrations and they have nothing stuff corresponded to other tables, you can specify these migrations(i.e. names of classes from Migrations folder) via `FenixAttribute`, and exactly they will be used as source of SQL scripts, which will be used for table creation:

```
[Fenix(nameof(Initial), nameof(MyTableFirstMigration), nameof(MyTableSecondMigration))]
public class MyTable
{
    //some stuff
}
```

Without this attribute, library will use *default* scripts. It is always better to specify migrations, because otherwise it is not guaranteed that all indexes will be created and also into your migrations you can include some custom code, that will not be executed at case of *default* solution.

Library is compatible and tested with EF 6.1.3 at case of MS SQL.