# Entity Framework with Federated Service implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

im not sure what im looking for, and everything that i've seen so far looks like it will work till I really dive into it. I just need some pointers from the brains here. Im working an ASP.NET MVC EF5 SQL2012 project. We have a model set that isn't code first (The entities were built using the designer) and as of right now, everything is working just fine. But, we have this setup script... (Convoluted as i've ever seen) and i need to get it into something more automated. Right now, the setup script pre-populates the tables with data. look ups, reference, etc. I'm looking for a way to automate this further, without having to run this script, and even more so. To generate the database and tables automatically. Every article i've read seems to do the trick (Migrations, seeding, etc.) but the one thing they don't take into consideration, we federate services. So the actual EDMX is on a WCF Dataservice 5.6. I have access to the models and what not but the WCF service exposes an DataServiceContext which doesn't have a seed on it. Am i looking at the right stuff here? or is the only option here to have this confounded setup script (All C# Driven). This website has been detrimental to this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx as well as this: [Auto Create Database Tables from Objects, Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873873/auto-create-database-tables-from-objects-entity-framework) but i don't see how i can use these over WCF 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that Model-First doesn't give you a seed method because they want you to use a SQL script, but you have a few choices:

1. Use EF PowerTools (or VS2013's EF Designer) to generate the "Code-First" model from your DB. This will allow you to seed your DB, and have finer control over how everything operates under the hood.
2. Use a SQL script to seed with. Generally, if you make changes to your schema, you'll re-run your recreate DB script. Create a separate script to populate your DB and keep it handy. If you feel more comfortable in code than SQL, you can make a console app (or whatever type of app you want) and keep it up to date with your schema.
3. If all you need is seed data, and there is a good business case to expose a method to your service consumers, you can keep Model-First, create a stored procedure to seed your DB, and expose it as an EF function. You can then expose this in your WCF service

Personally, I tend towards designing the DB myself, using VS 2013's EF6 POCO generator, then using Code-First because of the better granular control that you get with real data classes. Then I do some cleanup work, write my seed methods, etc.

Comment: Just an FYI uf you're still in the process of "considering" using WCF Data Services 5.6 and not fully committed... I recommend you look at WebApi instead. AFAIK, Microsoft dropped development on WCF Data Services after 5.6 pretty abruptly, and WebApi is the replacement. 

I only found this out after finding several bugs and severe limitations in WCF Data Services. I found a bunch of bugs in WebApi too, but they were known issues/had a planned fix date.