# Trying to add a controller, unable to retrieve metadata, no primary key define, even though it looks like there is

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

All the help I found so far said to define the primary key with [Key] and it must be named ID or *YourClassName*ID. As far as I can see i have this is the correct format but I'm still getting this error:

![Unable to retrieve metadata for 'DARTPRO.Models.Members'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

DARTPRO.Models.PlayerScores: :EntityType 'PlayerScores' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Players_Scores: EntityType: EntitySet 'Players_Scores' is based on tpye 'PlayerScores' that has no keys defined.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Caa.png)

When creating a controller like this:

![Model class: (DARTPRO.Models)

Data context class: DartConnection(DARTPRO.Models)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAWRn.png)

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DARTPRO.Models
{
    public class DartConnection : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Members> Member_Details { get; set;}
        public DbSet<PlayerScores> Players_Scores { get; set;}
    }

    [Table("MenmbersProfile")]
    public class Members
    {
        [Key]
        public int MembersID { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public string Contactnumber { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("PlayersGameDetials")]
    public class PlayerScores
    {
        [Key]
        public int PlayerScoresID { get; set; }
        public int HigestScore { get; set; }
        public double ThreeDartAverage { get; set; }
        public double OneDartAverage { get; set; }
        public int DartsThrown { get; set; }
        public int MembersID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have PlayerScoresID defined as primary key in database?

Comment: I have no tables in the database, that's what i'm trying to create now. I previously had tables in the database but deleted them due to the controller being missing on visual studio for some reason. Must not have saved it. Could this be effecting it?

Comment: If you want EF to create your database, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873873/auto-create-database-tables-from-objects-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks for the link, from what I'm reading off that I need to delete the database, however this isn't really possible. Is there no other way?

Comment: I never do it like this, instead, I use code first migrations to handle database changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code

[Table("MenmbersProfile")]
should that be MembersProfile? Me**n**mbers

[Table("PlayersGameDetials")]
Another typo? Details not Det**ia**ls.

I suggest manually create your database tables matching your code first classes and make sure you have no typos, and set Primary Keys on the tables in the database to match the [Key] attribute in your classes.

I also have the following override in my model, to control the pluralisation of table names.

Also if you want to control the target of the DbConext you can add your own contructor

```
public class DartConnection : DbContext
{
    public DartConnection()
    {
        // override the connection string
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyAppSettingDB"].ConnectionString;
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```